# Protractor-net, non angular login page

Tags: angularjs, protractor-net

Using protractor-net, Login page is `non-angular`, where as the home page is angular. hence cannot launch browser with `url` using `NgWebDriver`, probably since its looking for angular. tried `angular.ignoreSynchronization="false"`. But same issue. If I use `angDriver.WrappedDriver.FindElement` to cross login, the angular objects in home page are not recognized-`Asynchronous` script error-timeout.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\FTWork\\DriverFiles\\chromedriver_win32\\");
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
angDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver,"[ng-app='Phoenix']");
string root=angDriver.RootElement;
angDriver.WrappedDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
angDriver.WrappedDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver = angDriver.WrappedDriver;
driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserID")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserID")).SendKeys("");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("searchsubmit")).Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
string dolAmt = angDriver.FindElement(NgBy.Binding("activeValue")).Text;
```

Comment: I know exactly what you are facing. Is it a possiblity to share your login,how you are navigating to angular page objects?

Comment: @Saifur - Sorry, Wont be able to disclose login

But the ng-app is defined within html tag & body in it - but when we do rootElement- body is displayed
<html ng-app="Phoenix" ng-intro-options="IntroOptions" ng-intro-method="RunWalkthrough" ng-intro-onbeforechange="onIntroChange" ng-intro-onbeforestart="onIntroStart"
 <body ng-class="{'app-start': isReady}" class="app-start">

Answer (score 1):

I am hoping this will do it.

```
_driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\FTWork\\DriverFiles\\chromedriver_win32\\");
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));;
//Do whatever for log in with chrome driver

string url = "url for angular page";
_ngWebDriver = new NgWebDriver(_driver, "[ng-app='Phoenix']");
//You have to naviagate to url in order the _ngWebDriver to know the angular page NOT click and go to angular page
_ngWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
_ngWebDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
//The script timeout is almost essential since most of protractor mechanism are dependent of client side script.    

//start finding elements with NgBy class
NgWebElement ngElement = _ngWebDriver.FindElement(NgBy.Model("model"));
ngElement.Clear();
```

**EDIT**

```
driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\FTWork\\DriverFiles\\chromedriver_win32\\");
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserID")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserID")).SendKeys("");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("searchsubmit")).Click();


// Phoenix is the ng-app of the coming angular page
string url = "url for angular page containing [ng-app='Phoenix']"
NgWebDriver angDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver,"[ng-app='Phoenix']");

// don't switch to wrapper driver
angDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
angDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver = angDriver.WrappedDriver;
string dolAmt = angDriver.FindElement(NgBy.Binding("activeValue")).Text;
```

Comment: @Saifur-Tried the same as above yesterday, gave the angular page url directly. But was prompted the login prior which is non-angular, there it fails. Do we need to pass SetScriptTimeout or SetPageLoadTimeout, as above its SetPage.

Comment: Did you use `IwebDriver` for log in page or `NgWebDriver`? And, are you using PageObject pattern?

Comment: Fails at this step if I try to load the angular as Login displayed
angDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

InvstPortal.Navigation.TestLogin:
SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : Angular could not be found on the page - "Angular URL"
Used NgWebDriver

Comment: Is the loginPage angular page too?

Comment: No,Login not angular, hence the error.But Login displayed when try to navigate to angular URL. I think,that's the fix for rest of the angular objects in preceeding pages to be recognized.
So I have to use angDriver.WrappedDriver to launch the page.

Comment: So, use `IWebDriver` for log in. If possible share the code for log in and for navigating to the angular page

Comment: @Saifur-Updated my query with login code, cannot provide more info about logins. Raised different issue -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135247/angular-objects-not-recognized-protractor-net

Comment: @Chan1385 You totaly failed to follow what I am saying. If you switch back to wrapper driver you literally switching to `IWebDriver` which is not `NgWebDriver` anymore. See my edit

Comment: oh yeah, I got what you saying, tried that too. Adding driver.sendKeys() without switching to ngDriver prior to NgWebDriver angDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver,"[ng-app='Phoenix']") or navigate. Getting No such Element exception on UserID.
I did load the angular page again after the login by angDriver.Url=url. Same issue. Probably thinking, need to pass module in driver initialize, apart from rootElement

Comment: You should only instantiate the `NgWebDriver` right before navigating to the `angular` page

Comment: I think that is the approach to handle non-angular & angular navigation. lauched login using IWebDriver, login steps with iWebDriver, then instantiated NgWebDriver & navigated to angular url again. But still after that, unable to recognize angular objects on that page. Probably the way, the page is designed. Will try some other angular object.

Comment: Are you trying pageobject pattern or just a straight page for both drivers?

Comment: I am doing straight page (within single class) now,once it works I will use POM

Comment: @saifur-If there are multiple angular pages in project, is it good practice to initialize ngdriver in the constructor of pages rather in the main driver initialization script. That way we can pass ng-app= in page constructor.