# Angular objects not recognized -Protractor-net

Tags: angularjs, protractor, protractor-net

Script fails on this step on protractor-net ....NgWebDriver.cs file
probably on command step get('$browser') notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback)   - Any idea on what $browser or notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests used for?

```
this.jsExecutor.ExecuteAsyncScript(ClientSideScripts.WaitForAngular, this.rootElement)
angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser').notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Including the angDriver.IgnoreSynchronization=true statement solved it for me. Probably since my application is continuously polling for data so Requests never ends.